# Getting a compiler to generate adc instruction

Tags: c++, assembly, compiler-construction, optimization

Is there any way to get either Clang, GCC or VS to generate adc (add with carry) instructions only using Standard-C++(98/11/14)? (Edit: I mean in x64 mode, sorry if that wasn't clear.)

Comment: those are `c` compilers

Comment: @Taylor: "GCC" and "Visual Studio" 
are the names of compiler collections, which contain C++ compilers among others.  `clang` is a C++ compiler.

Comment: @BenVoigt oh, then I guess that makes sense.

Comment: FWIW, In x64, I've *never* been able to get any compiler to generate `adc` without inline assembly.

Comment: Is there any particular reason you want to do this?

Comment: You can play around with the gcc explorer, maybe that will get you somewhere.

Comment: The whole point of C or C++ is to isolate the programmer from platform-specific assembly. The C or C++ standards don't ever mention ADC (which is an implementation detail) so the answer is **no**. There's no guarantee that a particular processor provides an ADC instruction...

Comment: A definite no. *but*, there might be compiler extensions that are likely to yield one, e.g., clang's [__builtin_addc](http://clang.llvm.org/docs/LanguageExtensions.html#builtin-functions) functions.

Comment: @syam I never wanted a guarantee. I'm just looking for code examples which include enough hints for the optimizer to generate an adc instruction.

Comment: @OliCharlesworth Yes, I'd like to implement efficient arbitrary precision arithmetic in ISO-C++, but I don't think it's possible at the moment.

Comment: The problem is also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101507/is-there-anything-special-about-1-0xffffffff-regarding-adc

Comment: The problem is also related to https://stackoverflow.com/questions/56101507/is-there-anything-special-about-1-0xffffffff-regarding-adc

Answer (score 3):

If your code makes a comparison and adds the result of the comparison to something, then an `adc` is typically emitted by gcc 5 (incidentally, gcc 4.8 does not emit an `adc` here). For example,

```
unsigned foo(unsigned a, unsigned b, unsigned c, unsigned d)
{
    return (a + b + (c < d));
}
```

assembles to

```
foo:
    cmpl    %ecx, %edx
    movl    %edi, %eax
    adcl    %esi, %eax
    ret
```

However, it is a bit tricky to get gcc to really emit an `adc`.

Comment: Yup, it is hard to get gcc to emit `adc` for conditional increments like the above. I _think_ gcc has a peephole or other stage that takes an `adc` with a `0` immediate and turns into a (generally worse on modern hardware) `xor eax, eax; setb al; add ..., eax` sequence. For example, if you remove `b` from the above so it is `(a + (c < d))` the natural sequence would be to use an `adc` with `0` but gcc does the weird `setb` thing. Same for ternary expression like `a += (c < d) ? 1 : 0`. However, if you do `a += (c < d) ? 3 : 2` or any other off-by-one values it _does_ use `adc eax, 2`.

Comment: So it seems only when `0` would be the immediate it does this weirdness. Also, if you use a branch, like `if (c < d) a++` it uses `adc`! I tried out [many examples on godbolt](https://godbolt.org/g/cGiU5p).

Answer (score 2):

There's an `__int128_t` type available on GCC for amd64 and other 64bit targets, which will use a pair of `add`/`adc` instructions for a simple addition.  (See the Godbolt link below).

Also, this pure ISO C code may compile to an adc:

```
uint64_t adc(uint64_t a, uint64_t b)
{
    a += b;
    if (a < b) /* should simplify to nothing (setting carry is implicit in the add) */
        a++; /* should simplify to adc r0, 0 */
    return a;
}
```

For me (ARM) it generated something kind of silly, but it compiles for x86-64 (on the [Godbolt compiler explorer](http://gcc.godbolt.org/#compilers:!((compiler:g530,options:'-xc+-std%3Dgnu11+-fverbose-asm+-Wall+-Wextra+-O3++-fno-tree-vectorize',source:'%23include+%3Cstdint.h%3E%0A%0Auint64_t+adc(uint64_t+a,+uint64_t+b)%0A%7B%0A++++a+%2B%3D+b%3B%0A++++if+(a+%3C+b)+/*+should+simplify+to+nothing+(setting+carry+is+implicit+in+the+add)+*/%0A++++++++a%2B%2B%3B+/*+should+simplify+to+adc+r0,+0+*/%0A++++return+a%3B%0A%7D%0A%0A//+gcc+wastes+a+bunch+of+mov+instructions,+but+clang+doesn!'t%0A__uint128_t+add128(__uint128_t+a,+__uint128_t+b)+%7B%0A++return+a+%2B+b%3B%0A%7D')),filterAsm:(commentOnly:!t,directives:!t,intel:!t,labels:!t),version:3)) to this:

```
    mov     rax, rdi  # a, a
    add     rax, rsi  # a, b
    adc     rax, 0    # a,
    ret
```

Comment: I was going to add that I think `-funsafe-math-optimizations` might kill off that whole `if` block, but it doesn't seem to.  I think C might allow such an optimisation, though, so look out there.

Comment: unsigned wraparound is well-defined in C/C++, as binary integer.  It's guaranteed to work properly.  `-funsafe-math-optimizations` only affects floating point behaviour.  Maybe you're thinking of signed integer wraparound being undefined behaviour?  `-fwrapv` makes it well-defined (as 2's complement), but is *not* enabled by default.

Answer (score 1):

If you compile a 64-bit signed addition for X86 (`int64_t` in C++ 11), the compiled code will contain an `adc` instruction.

Edit: code sample:

```
int64_t add_numbers(int64_t x, int64_t y) {
    return x + y;
}
```

On X86, the addition is implemented using an `add` instruction followed by an `adc` instruction. On X64, only a single `add` instruction is used.

Comment: Can you give a minimal example function? I have never seen it in any of my binaries, only lea(q) and similar.

Comment: Please see my edit, I should have included this before. The background here is to see if it is possible to build efficient arbitrary integer arithmetic in Standard-C++. :)